# Can i make Jboss Tools plugin to run on JDK 32 while run Eclipse on JDK 64?

Tags: eclipse, java, jboss-tools

Can i make Jboss Tools plugin to run on JDK 32 while run Eclipse on JDK 64?

I wanted to do this because i need to assign more memory to eclipse while making Jboss tools (visual editor) use the 32 jdk hence it doesn't on 64.

noting i am running a Windows 7 64, if yes how can i achieve this?

Comment: I don't see how; Eclipse plugins run in the same VM as Eclipse.

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  Why wouldn't you want everything to run on the 64 bit JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i make Jboss Tools plugin to run on JDK 32 while run Eclipse on JDK 64?

Assuming you are talking about a plugin for Eclipse, the answer is - No.

A plugin for Eclipse runs in the same JVM as Eclipse itself.  That has to be either 32 bit or 64 bit.  It can't be both!

---

Why do you need to "making Jboss tools use the 32 jdk"?  Do you mean that you want it to launch a 32bit JVM to run JBoss?  If so, then you should be able to do this either via preferences in the JBoss plugin or via the relevant application launcher configuration.  (Maybe someone with experience with this particular plugin could chime in with specific details.)

But lets be clear, this is NOT making the "Jboss Tools plugin to run on JDK 32" ...

Comment: thanks, just checked jboss tools website, the plugin only working in 32 JDK, and i can't do the configuration that i asked for above

Comment: *"just checked jboss tools website, the plugin only working in 32 JDK"*.  Where does it say that?  http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_3.html says nothing about requiring a 32bit JDK.

Comment: check here http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/2.0/html/Getting_Started_with_JBoss_Developer_Studio_Guide/getting_started.html

Comment: Well, I suggest that you stop using that pre-packaged version and install the JBoss Tools plugins directly into a 64bit Eclipse release.  Alternatively, if you have RedHat support, ask them if there is a 64bit version of JBDS for your platform.